error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400
Enumerating objects: 5545, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5545/5545), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5320/5320), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (5545/5545), 1.54 GiB | 2.34 MiB/s, done.
Total 5545 (delta 990), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
i already used this comands but till i am facing the same error
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
git push -u origin main
